# MySQL Query to set unique numbers in column via data linked in 2nd table

Tags: mysql, join, set

I'll try to explain this as simply as I can.

Overview:

This is for a game server. In the game the characters have normal items, and then there are equipments which have stats on them. I want to give certain special pieces of equipment a uniqueid. Each count of the special equipment should have a different uniqueid, even if the player has two of the same piece of equipment. There are two tables related to items, inventoryitems and then there is inventoryequipment. Normal items will be simply in the inventoryitems table as they do not have stats, however equipments are shown in inventoryitems and also in inventoryequipment where the stats for that item are stored. These two tables are linked by a column called inventoryitemid.

What am I trying to do:

I would like to make a query which will set a unique number in the uniqueid column in inventoryitems to any items which are an equipment which has certain stats.

Here's a broken example query which obviously wont work but hopefully it will help you understand further what I am trying to accomplish...

```
 UPDATE inventoryitems 
 SET    inventoryitems.uniqueid = (
                 SELECT MAX(uniqueid)) + 1 
                 WHERE EXISTS 
                 (
                     SELECT inventoryequipment.inventoryitemid 
                     FROM   inventoryequipment 
                     WHERE  inventoryequipment.upgradeslots = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.level = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.str = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.dex = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.int = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.luk = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.hp = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.mp = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.watk = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.wdef = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.mdef = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.acc = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.hands = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.speed = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.jump = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.ringid = -1 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.locked = 0 
                        &&  inventoryequipment.isRing = 0
                   );
```

Comment: Currently the above query does not seem to check for the equipments stats and simply changes all rows in inventoryitems and sets them all to have uniqueid set to 1. So I'd want the query to check for the stats and then set each applicable row to +1 of the highest value in the uniqueid column... So that each row does actually have a unique number in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
set @i=0;
UPDATE inventoryitems SET uniqueid = (@i:=@i+1) WHERE inventoryitemid IN (SELECT inventoryequipment.inventoryitemid 
                 FROM   inventoryequipment 
                 WHERE  inventoryequipment.upgradeslots = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.level = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.str = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.dex = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.int = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.luk = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.hp = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.mp = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.watk = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.wdef = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.mdef = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.acc = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.hands = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.speed = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.jump = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.ringid = -1 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.locked = 0 
                    &&  inventoryequipment.isRing = 0);
```